# Use additional array in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would really appreciate your help.

I want to use an additional array with foreach.

Currently it looks like this and works perfectly.

```
<?php

$listcity = array("Negril" => "negril",
"Kingston" => "kingston",
"Ocho Rios" => "ocho-rios");

foreach ($listcity as $cityname => $citylink) {
    echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example.com/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Now I want to add a span with the following numbers:

```
 $distancemiles = array("Negril" => "25",
  "Kingston" => "10",
  "Ocho Rios" => "67");
```

I want the final echo to be the following:

```
<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a><span>(HERE THE DISTANCE IN MILES miles)</span></li>
```

so that the browser outputs for instance:

[Negril (50 miles)](https://example/hotels/negril)

> So I would like to know how I can combine my three sources of data:
>
> **$cityname** --> Should be the name of the city
>   **$citylink**  --> Should be the link ending
>   **$distancetocity**  --> Should be the distance

Would someone help me with this? I've tried very hard to make it work and read through all kinds of online tutorials, but I fail every time.

Best,

Max

Comment: how do you get the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find distance of city by it name. The `$distancemiles[$cityname]` return distance of city.

```
foreach ($listcity as $cityname => $citylink){
    echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\">
        <a href=\"https://example.com/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a>
        <span>$distancemiles[$cityname]</span>
    </li>";
}
```

See result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/QSFYH)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$listcity = array("Negril" => "negril",
"Kingston" => "kingston",
"Ocho Rios" => "ocho-rios");

$distancemiles = array("Negril" => "25",
  "Kingston" => "10",
  "Ocho Rios" => "67");

foreach ($listcity as $cityname => $citylink) {
    echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a><span>($distancemiles[$cityname])</span></li>";
}
?>
```

You can look up the value of the miles using your distance array.

Your array list city array has structure cityname->linkname your distance array has structure cityname->distanceInMiles so you can use the city name from your for loop to look up the distance at the index of the cityname.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do:

```
echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example.com/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a><span>{$distancemiles[$cityname]}</span></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

using [arrray_merge_recursive](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive)
 :

merge your array into one array, then access it as follows:

```
$listcity = array("Negril" => "negril",
"Kingston" => "kingston",
"Ocho Rios" => "ocho-rios");

$distancemiles = array("Negril" => "25",
  "Kingston" => "10",
  "Ocho Rios" => "67");

$oneArray = array_merge_recursive($listcity, $distancemiles);


foreach ($oneArray as $cityname => $citylink) {
    echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example/hotels/".$citylink[0]."\">$cityname</a><span>".$citylink[1]."</span></li>";
}
```

live example: https://3v4l.org/Q0VDn

Answer (score 0):

If you add a reference to the `$distancemiles` array with `$cityname` as key (like `$distancemiles[$cityname]`) you can get the miles within the foreach loop.

```
$listcity = array(
    "Negril" => "negril",
    "Kingston" => "kingston",
    "Ocho Rios" => "ocho-rios");

$distancemiles = array("Negril" => "25",
  "Kingston" => "10",
  "Ocho Rios" => "67");

foreach ($listcity as $cityname => $citylink) {
    echo "<li data-name=\"$cityname Hotels\"><a href=\"https://example.com/hotels/$citylink\">$cityname</a><span>$distancemiles[$cityname]</span></li>";
}

// Negril25
// Kingston10
// Ocho Rios67
```